# Importing excel sheet using tkinter and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I want to import two xlsx using a browse buttons :

This is the code i used:

```
app=Tk()

def callback():
    chart_path=askopenfilename()
    return

file_location1=Button(app,text="TB v1",width=15, command=callback)
file_location1.pack(side='top')

file_location2=Button(app,text="TB v2",width=15, command=callback)
file_location2.pack(side='top')

wb1= openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location1)
ws1= wb1.active

wb2= openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location2)
ws2=wb2.active
```

But when I build the script , I receive this error:  TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not Button

Is anyone which can help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider encapsulating your code to code block to increase readability of your question as well as chances of it being answered quickly.

Comment: You're passing a button to `file_location1` which is exactly what the error is telling you. Why do you think you should pass a button to this function?

Comment: I want to combine tkinter with openpyxl. I think it possible to import with browser button a xlsx then use openpyxl to work on that excel. But i dont know exactly how to do ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a button where the file_name should be, try like this:

Import all modules first

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

Create your window :

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
```

Then create your function :

```
def open_file():

    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx *.xlsm *.sxc *.ods *.csv *.tsv')]) # To open the file that you want. 
    #' mode='r' ' is to tell the filedialog to read the file
    # 'filetypes=[()]' is to filter the files shown as only Excel files

    wb = load_workbook(filename = file.name) # Load into openpyxl
    wb2 = wb.active

    #Whatever you want to do with the WorkSheet
```

then everything else :

```
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = open_file)
btn.pack(side='top')



mainloop()
```